# Java order of precedence

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I just came across a piece of code I find interesting (because I have never seen it as a question before in 2 years of programming)

```
int x = 5;
int y = 3;
int z = y + (y+=1) % 4 + (x-=2) / 3;
System.out.println(z);
```

The output is 4.

I am wondering why is the left most 'y' evaluated first instead of the '(y+=1)' which would then resulted in an output of 5. (in other words, why is the bracket not forcing the order of precedence?)

I am not sure what to search since searching 'java order of precedence' returns results that at best shows tricky examples of y++, ++y kind of questions or just the order of precedence table.

I tagged Java but I have tested this with C# and javascript so it is probably a general thing in programming.

## Update

I was mistaken about the order of precedence and order of evaluation.

This [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/) helped me to further understand the answers provided.

Comment: What is strange about evaluating the left-most term first?

Comment: You wouldn't see that as a question because any programmer worth his salt wouldn't write something like that. These kinds of questions are quite worthless.

Comment: @JFMeier I would like to know why the bracket '(y+=1)' was not done first.

Comment: @Kayaman I know that no 1 would write something like this, it is just 1 of those academic questions used to test students on their understanding of order of precedence.

Comment: @Kayaman Sure, nobody would write this in production code.  But this kind of exercise is really good for making us think about order of operations.  To me, it's not obvious that the `y` on the left should be evaluated before the `(y += 1)`.

Comment: @Stein121 I think the answers nail it. Java specified to evaluate sums from left to right. That is exactly what happens here.

Comment: A better question would be: What made you think that (y += 1) should be evaluated first?  That's obviously wrong if you read about operator precedence.  Why do you continue to insist on it?

Comment: Don't confuse precedence with order of evaluation. The brackets change how the expression is parsed but not the order of evaluation.

Comment: @duffymo I thought that (y += 1) should be evaluated first because I thought expression with brackets would be evaluated first. But obviously I was wrong to think that.

Comment: Yes, left to right comes first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short, the parentheses only apply to a particular *term*.

The expression `y + (y+=1) % 4 + (x-=2) / 3;` can be rewritten as `t1 + t2 + t3`, with `t1` standing for `y`, `t2` for `(y+=1) % 4`, and `t3` for `(x-=2) / 3`.

Java *always* evaluates this from left to right, since the *associativity* of the *binary operator* `+` is from left to right. Hence `t1` is the first term to be evaluated and so is done so with the *unincremented* value of `y`.

Comment: This is the key - evaluation is always LTR. I believe in C++ the evaluation order is _undefined_...

Comment: Indeed, the evaluation of `+` is from LTR: I've added that. Note that ternary conditionals, for example, are evaluated from RTL.

Comment: This is the order most western language are read left to right.  Arabic, Hebrew are read right to left by comparison.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: In C++ and C, the value of this this expression is indeed *undefined*. But it's more to do with the fact that `+` is not a *sequencing* point in C and C++, as opposed to the order of evaluation.

Comment: @Bathsheba I am assuming that t1 is 'y', t2 is '(y+=1) % 4' and t3 is '(x-=2) / 3'? If that is so then would it be right to say that for it to be t1 + t2 + t3, '(y+=1)' needs to be evaluated first?

Comment: A source of confusion is school mathematics teachers who say you should evaluate brackets first (with mnemonics such as BODMAS). Unfortunately, people tend to confuse *precedence order* with *evaluation order*, They are totally different things.

Comment: @Stein121 no. For a left associative operator, the LHS is always evaluated first. There is nothing special about `+=`. The machine doesn't even _look_ at the RHS until it know the value of the LHS.

Comment: We agree on the definitions of t1, t2, and t3. But no, t1 is evaluated first before *anything* to do with t2 is considered.

Comment: @BoristheSpider So essentially, what is happening is java first comes up with the order of evaluation? then get the values of t1, t2, t3, starting form t1? thus resulting in t1 not being affected by the operations done in t2? Am I right to say this?

Comment: @Stein121 not quite. Java evaluates `t1` then `t2` then `t1 + t2` then `t3`; because `t1 + t2` is the LHS of `(t1 + t2) + t3` and needs to be evaluated first.

Answer (score 8):

As per Java language Specs [Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First and Evaluate Operands before Operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1)

Comment: This is the correct answer - the fact that evaluation order is prescribed by the Java Language Specification.